# Capture REST calls with Selenium

Tags: javascript, rest, selenium, webdriver-io

I run integration test with Selenium as a test runner and [webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io/) javascript library for Selenium API.
My test goes as follows:
I load an html page and click on a button. I want to check if a Get REST call was invoked.

I found a plugin for webdriver.io called [webdriverajax](https://github.com/chmanie/webdriverajax) that intend to fit to my requirements but it just doesn't work.

Any ideas how do capture rest calls?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using custom `HttpClient` class that is out side from selenium code.As far as i know selenium doesn't support this feature.

Assume when you clicked the button it will called a `REST` service , the URL can be grab from the `HTML` `DOM` element.Then you can use your custom code to verify if URL is accessible or not.Then you can decide if your test is pass or failed based on the `status code` or some other your mechanism.

**FileDownloader.java(Sample code snippet)**

```
private String downloader(WebElement element, String attribute) throws IOException, NullPointerException, URISyntaxException {
        String fileToDownloadLocation = element.getAttribute(attribute);
        if (fileToDownloadLocation.trim().equals("")) throw new NullPointerException("The element you have specified does not link to anything!");

        URL fileToDownload = new URL(fileToDownloadLocation);
        File downloadedFile = new File(this.localDownloadPath + fileToDownload.getFile().replaceFirst("/|\\\\", ""));
        if (downloadedFile.canWrite() == false) downloadedFile.setWritable(true);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        BasicHttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

        LOG.info("Mimic WebDriver cookie state: " + this.mimicWebDriverCookieState);
        if (this.mimicWebDriverCookieState) {
            localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, mimicCookieState(this.driver.manage().getCookies()));
        }

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(fileToDownload.toURI());
        HttpParams httpRequestParameters = httpget.getParams();
        httpRequestParameters.setParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, this.followRedirects);
        httpget.setParams(httpRequestParameters);

        LOG.info("Sending GET request for: " + httpget.getURI());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget, localContext);
        this.httpStatusOfLastDownloadAttempt = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        LOG.info("HTTP GET request status: " + this.httpStatusOfLastDownloadAttempt);
        LOG.info("Downloading file: " + downloadedFile.getName());
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(response.getEntity().getContent(), downloadedFile);
        response.getEntity().getContent().close();

        String downloadedFileAbsolutePath = downloadedFile.getAbsolutePath();
        LOG.info("File downloaded to '" + downloadedFileAbsolutePath + "'");

        return downloadedFileAbsolutePath;
    }
```

**TestClass.java**

```
@Test
public void downloadAFile() throws Exception {


       FileDownloader downloadTestFile = new FileDownloader(driver);
        driver.get("http://www.localhost.com/downloadTest.html");
        WebElement downloadLink = driver.findElement(By.id("fileToDownload"));
        String downloadedFileAbsoluteLocation = downloadTestFile.downloadFile(downloadLink);

        assertThat(new File(downloadedFileAbsoluteLocation).exists(), is(equalTo(true)));
        assertThat(downloadTestFile.getHTTPStatusOfLastDownloadAttempt(), is(equalTo(200)));
 // you can use status code to valid  the REST URL
    }
```

[Here](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/) is the reference.

**Note:** This may not exactly fit into your requirement but you can get some idea and modify it accordingly to fit into your requirement.

Also refer the [BrowserMob Proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) using this you can also achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the webdriver.io version. Apparently, webdriverajax works fine just with webdriver.io v3.x but not with v4.x. I use v4.5.2.

I decide not using a plugin and implement a mock for window.XMLHttpRequest
open and send methods, as follows:

```
proxyXHR() {
  this.browser.execute(() => {
    const namespace = '__scriptTests';
    window[namespace] = { open: [], send: [] };
    const originalOpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (...args) {
      window[namespace].open.push({
        method: args[0],
        url: args[1],
        async: args[2],
        user: args[3],
        password: args[4]
      });
      originalOpen.apply(this, [].slice.call(args));
    };
    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (...args) {
      window[namespace].send.push(JSON.parse(args[0]));
    };
  });
}

getXHRsInfo() {
  const result = this.browser.execute(() => {
    const namespace = '__scriptTests';
    return window[namespace];
  });
  return result.value;
}
```